# Trouble Appending <div> to existing

Tags: jquery

I've got the following and I'm trying to add divs inside the container div:

the container div is at the top of the page and is setup like this:

```
<div id="facebookPhotosContainer" />
```

now here's the code to populate that div with thumbnails:

```
    function ShowThumbnails(aThumbs, sPhotoContainerDivID)
    {
        alert("sPhotoContainerDivID: " + sPhotoContainerDivID);
        photoContainer = "div#" + sPhotoContainerDivID;

        for(i = 0, l = aThumbs.length; i < l; i++)
        {
            alert("appending");
            $(photoContainer).append("<div id='thumnailContainer'><img src=" + aThumbs[i].photoSrc + " class='thumbnail' /></div>");
            //$("<div id='uploadThumnailContainer'><img src=" + aThumbs[i].photoSrc + " class='thumbnail' ></img></div>").appendTo("div#" + sPhotoContainerDivID);
        }
    }
```

Nothing is showing up.  Not sure what I'm missing...but it is getting inside the loop and calling the code to try to append here.

Side note: this code is in a page that sits inside an IFrame.

*UPDATE:*

Here's my latest, still not rendering to the page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="photos-iFrameContent">
        <div>
            <p>Log in</p>
            <p id="loginButtonContainer"><input type="image" id="btnFacebookLogin" src="images/facebookLoginBtn.jpg" /></p>
            <p><select id="albumDropdown" /></p>
            <div id="facebookPhotosContainer" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

    function ShowAlbumPhotoThumbnails(aAlbumPhotos, sPhotoContainerDivID)
    {
        alert("sPhotoContainerDivID: " + sPhotoContainerDivID);
        photoContainer = "#" + sPhotoContainerDivID;

        for(i = 0, l = aAlbumPhotos.length; i < l; i++)
        {
            alert("about to append a new div:  aAlbumPhotos[i].facebookPhotoPageSrc: " + aAlbumPhotos[i].facebookPhotoPageSrc);
            alert("html that will be spit out to the page: " + "<div class='uploadThumnailContainer'><img src='" + aAlbumPhotos[i].facebookPhotoPageSrc + "' class='thumbnail' /></div>");
            $(photoContainer).append("<div class='uploadThumnailContainer'><img src='" + aAlbumPhotos[i].facebookPhotoPageSrc + "' class='thumbnail' /></div>");
        }
    }
```

here's an example of incoming data from those alerts I have set up:

about to append a new div:  aAlbumPhotos[i].fullSizePhotoSrc: http://sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/hs098.ash2/38258_1435105371111_1637262814_1014688_8078397_n.jpg

html that will be spit out to the page:

html that will be spit out to the page:

Comment: I wonder if this is due to the lack of the required img tag attribute for alt=''?

Comment: should it not be: $(photoContainer).append("<div class='uploadThumnailContainer'><img src='" + aAlbumPhotos[i].facebookPhotoPageSrc + "' class='thumbnail' alt='' /></div>");

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's a good catch.  ).append("<div class='uploadThumnailContainer'><img src='" + aAlbumPhotos[i].facebookPhotoPageSrc + "' class='thumbnail' alt='facebookUpload' /></div>");  but this did not fix the problem.  I'm looking at this thinking what else could it be!  Weird.

Comment: It must be the way I'm using jQuery becaue I took this and hard coded it into the page and it shows the image just fine:  <img src='http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/hs098.ash2/38258_1435105371111_1637262814_1014688_8078397_s.jpg' class='thumbnail' alt='facbookUpload' /  and this was the text it's appending or trying to append to that div

Comment: You might try appendTo() instead of append(), just thinking...

Comment: appendTo doesn't work...at least in my code and it wasn't the right one to use after I read it on the jQuery docs page even before posting this thread.  I also tried prepend with no luck.

Comment: So this code is in an IFrame.  The JS and HTML here.  Now if I'm naturally loading this IFrame's parent page when testing, is it possible that the JS is trying to be applied to its master and not itself the child?  If that were the case then that div placeholder would not exist but I do not know how the DOM loads in cases when you have an IFrame involved and logic in it...I don't know what context is calling the code (parent to iframe or iframe first then to parent)

Comment: See my updated (new) answer with a fiddle page to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/v7qTP/
 by removal of the empty select

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div id="photos-iFrameContent"> 
        <div> 
            <p>Log in</p> 
            <p id="loginButtonContainer"><input type="image" id="btnFacebookLogin" src="images/facebookLoginBtn.jpg" /></p> 
                        <div id="facebookPhotosContainer" />
    </div> 
</form>
```

here is the code I used to verify (added the object and function call to have a source)

```
var myphoto = [{facebookPhotoPageSrc:'http://sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/hs098.ash2/38258_1435105371111_1637262814_1014688_8078397_n.jpg'}];
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      ShowAlbumPhotoThumbnails(myphoto,"facebookPhotosContainer");
                  });
function ShowAlbumPhotoThumbnails(aAlbumPhotos, sPhotoContainerDivID) 
{ 
    //alert("sPhotoContainerDivID: " + sPhotoContainerDivID); 
    photoContainer = "#" + sPhotoContainerDivID; 

    for(i = 0, l = aAlbumPhotos.length; i < l; i++) 
    { 
       // alert("about to append a new div:  aAlbumPhotos[i].facebookPhotoPageSrc: " + aAlbumPhotos[i].facebookPhotoPageSrc); 
        //alert("html that will be spit out to the page: " + "<div class='uploadThumnailContainer'><img src='" + aAlbumPhotos[i].facebookPhotoPageSrc + "' class='thumbnail' /></div>"); 
        $(photoContainer).append("<div class='uploadThumnailContainer'><img src='" + aAlbumPhotos[i].facebookPhotoPageSrc + "' class='thumbnail' /></div>"); 
    } 
}
```

sample with two objects in the array:

```
var myphoto = [{facebookPhotoPageSrc:'http://sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/hs098.ash2/38258_1435105371111_1637262814_1014688_8078397_n.jpg'},{facebookPhotoPageSrc:'http://sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/hs098.ash2/38258_1435105371111_1637262814_1014688_8078397_n.jpg'}];
```

Comment: thanks for the jsfiddle, did not know about that tool...probably common but I don't really code a lot of JS until now.

Comment: on your var, why did you specify }] ?

Comment: Weird, I need that select there.  hmm.

Comment: ah!  ok problem was you can't shortcut a select <select /> f's it all up...I needed <select></select>

Comment: I put the [] in because of your array processing - I could have created multiple images to insert this way by adding more {} objects.

Comment: Added a sample of your named object with two entries in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If your sources have any sort of spacing or quotes it'll throw it way off with invalid HTML, make sure your have quotes on your `src=""` and use a class instead of an ID for the `<div>` wrapper, like this:

```
$(photoContainer).append("<div class='thumnailContainer'><img src='" + aThumbs[i].photoSrc + "' class='thumbnail' /></div>");
```

Or a bit easier/cleaner using the[`$(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) method:

```
$("<img />", { src: aThumbs[i].photoSrc, "class": "thumbnail" })
   .wrap("<div class='thumnailContainer'></div>")
   .appendTo(photoContainer);
```

The ID on the wrapper isn't a good idea since it's in a loop and will not be unique if there' more than one thumbnail here.  It isn't likely causing your current issue, but better to fix it anyway.

Comment: I don't get the issue with putting an ID on the wrapper...wrappers should have an ID because there's only one of them on the page.  Inside are the different divs for each thumbnail

Comment: you're talking about the thumbnail div that has the ID, yea that should be a class, good catch.

Comment: or I could use "" and "" instead of '" and '" right?  no difference, just a different route to go (all quotes)

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - Yep, but if it has quotes you'll still have issues, just be careful that's not the case...my second method, the quotes won't matter either way.

Comment: no luck: $(photoContainer).append("<div class='thumnailContainer'><img src='" + aAlbumPhotos[i].photoSrc + "' class='thumbnail' /></div>");

Comment: ok, so just wondering why using quotes instead of ' causes issues if there are space chars in the values...I mean why would ' fix that?  Does it perform some sort of automatic trim by using '' instead  of "" for the values?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - Think about how it looks without quotes: `<img src=http://mysite.com/image.jpg />`, a syntax nightmare for a browser, hence it needs to be in quotes :)

Comment: Ah did not realize that.  Yea, it would not have any quotes around it unless you do a "" ""  or ' '.

Comment: I don't know it's still not rendering and I can't view the source since it's in an IFrame.  There are tools out there (plug-ins) to Mozilla so you can easily view Iframe source but they screw up my Facebook implementation...cause errors on the login page.

Answer (score 0):

try just

```
$('#id')
```

where id is the id